# Loading an image with a button click

Tags: java, android, url, button, imageview

I have this button which loads an image from an URL. I tried setting the ImageView visibility to Invisible so when I start the app the image doesn't show up until I click the button. But I want to know, is there any other way? Any other way to make it work **without setting the ImageView's visibility to invisible**.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://test.please.do/app/car.jpg";
    ImageView imageView;
    Button buttonPlay;
    Button buttonFullScreen;
    Button buttonLoad;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;
    MediaController mediacontroller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        resultvideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        final ImageView url = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://test.please.do/app/car.jpg").into(url);

        buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
        {
            buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your goal? why you should need another way of doing it?

Comment: I want to show the ImageView box first without the image until I click the button.

Comment: Maybe your problem is thast the image is taking space even when invisible? If that's the case, you should use `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`. It's unclear your objective though

Comment: There's no objective, I just wanted to know if there's any other way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE), the view still take the space even if it is shown as transparent. If you want to totally hide the ImageView, you should use [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE).

The difference is simply that View.GONE collapse the view so the space is not left empty for her.

From the two links above:

**View.INVISIBLE**

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

**View.GONE**

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
> Se the two links for more informations

## Edit

Another possible way could be adding by code the imageView after the button click.. Or another way could be setting height of the imageView to `0dp` and then back to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Those are *possibilities, you can do it*. But **I highly reccoment using `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` for handling stuffs like this since it is the "Standard" for View behaviours**

Comment: I know but what I want to happen is to show the ImageView and then image after button is clicked.

Comment: @JoeF I know and this is what it does.. I mean to change in your XML to change the "INVISIBLE" keyword to the "GONE" one. btw i added a couple of examples of things u can do, but using View.GONE and View.VISIBLE is the best one

Answer (score 0):

change

```
final ImageView url = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://test.please.do/app/car.jpg").into(url);

    buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
    {
        buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

to

```
final ImageView url = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
        buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {             
Picasso.with(this).load("http://test.please.do/app/car.jpg").into(url);
            }
        });
```

and try to remove the code to make it invisible

Comment: change it to MainActivity.this

Comment: It just loads the image on startup, I haven't click the button yet.

Comment: have you provided any default image in xml,if yes remove it and if not  try uninstalling and then installing it again in case if anything is cached

Answer (score 0):

You should add the image button after the old layout.
like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <variable..../>
    <ImageButton..../>
</RelativeLayout>
```